# Block outgoing TCP connection to a given host or IP?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, tcp, block

Is it possible to intercept an outgoing TCP connection to a given host or IP in Windows and block that connection on the TCP level, i.e. at the `connect(...)` layer? Or prevent connection to a specific IP in the first place?

Or do I need to write a packet filter to intercept traffic to a certain address?

Comment: What OS? This process is very OS dependent.

Comment: @Scott: Windows. Added to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably best to simply use the system's firewall API.  On Windows:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366449(v=VS.85).aspx

Otherwise you are going to be writing drivers and such... complete hassle considering the functionality is built into the OS these days.

Comment: I would prefer it if my implementation did not depend on the Windows Firewall service and the less modification for 2000/XP/Vista/Win7, the better. But this may be the preferred solution. Would `INetFwService` allow me to programmatically block outgoing TCP traffic to a remote IP?

Comment: @FreshCode, I've never used it myself, but at a quick glance, it does appear to at least be in the right direction of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

On linux? Configure iptables to drop the connection, perhaps.